# Where is one supposed to call torch.distributed.destroy_process_group() in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, distributed-computing

I noticed that the docs do not have that function. Thus, it's unclear where one should be calling that. Does one have to:

1. call it at the end of each worker code (i.e. inside of mp.spawn)
2. or call it outside of mp.spawn i.e. by the main process

Note there is a gitissue requesting to put this function on the docs: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/48203

this is an example of what 2 means:

```
def test_setup():
    print('test_setup')
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
    else:
        world_size = 4
    master_port = find_free_port()
    mp.spawn(setup_process, args=(world_size, master_port), nprocs=world_size)
    dist.destroy_process_group()
    print('successful test_setup!')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that in the [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html#basic-use-case) the function `cleanup()` is called at the end of each process (i.e. inside mp.spawn)

```
def cleanup():
    dist.destroy_process_group()
```